# pyqt5: some widgets are disappear in my label

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am implement my-self label, but some widget is disappear.

My code is:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys


class TypeManagerLabel(QLabel):


    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        btnLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.__nameLineEdit = QLineEdit()
        self.__opBtn = QPushButton('Add/Remove')
        self.__colorBtn = QPushButton('Color')
        btnLayout.addWidget(self.__nameLineEdit)
        btnLayout.addWidget(self.__opBtn)
        layout.addLayout(btnLayout)


class MyWin(QLabel):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        lab1 = TypeManagerLabel()
        layout.addWidget(lab1)
        # layout.addStretch()
        lab2 = QPushButton('test')
        layout.addWidget(lab2)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
dialog = MyWin()
dialog.show()
app.exec_()
```

Currently, the label is OK, and the result should be:

[image]

Now, I want the QLineEdit should be located on the top of the label, thus I add a stretch. And the code is:

```
class MyWin(QLabel):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        lab1 = TypeManagerLabel()
        layout.addWidget(lab1)
        layout.addStretch()  ###################### add the stretch
        lab2 = QPushButton('test')
        layout.addWidget(lab2)
```

And the result is:

[image]

In the above figure, the QLineEdit is disappeared.

@

My environment is:

```
win 10
python 3.7.8
pyqt5 5.14.0
```

---

--------------------------------update ----------------------------------

Thank for the suggestion from musicamante and Heike, subclass QWidget instead of QLabel. But the new bug is reported after I add some new widget. The code is:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys


class TypeManagerLabel(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        btnLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.__nameLineEdit = QLineEdit()
        self.__opBtn = QPushButton('Add')
        btnLayout.addWidget(self.__nameLineEdit)
        btnLayout.addWidget(self.__opBtn)

        layout.addLayout(btnLayout)

        infoLabel = QLabel()
        layout.addWidget(infoLabel)

        self.__infoLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        infoLabel.setLayout(self.__infoLayout)

        self.__opBtn.clicked.connect(self.addRemoveSlot)


    def addRemoveSlot(self, checked=False):

        name = self.__nameLineEdit.text()
        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        checkBox = QCheckBox()
        lineEdit = QLineEdit(name)
        layout.addWidget(checkBox)
        layout.addWidget(lineEdit)
        self.__infoLayout.addLayout(layout)


class MyWin(QLabel):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        lab1 = TypeManagerLabel()
        layout.addWidget(lab1)
        # layout.addStretch()
        lab2 = QPushButton('test')
        layout.addWidget(lab2)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
dialog = MyWin()
dialog.show()
app.exec_()
```

When I input a string in the QLineEdit, and click the "Add" button, the result is:

[image]

The above figure is what I expected.

But if I add stretch with the code:

```
class MyWin(QLabel):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        lab1 = TypeManagerLabel()
        layout.addWidget(lab1)
        layout.addStretch() ###################### add the stretch
        lab2 = QPushButton('test')
        layout.addWidget(lab2)
```

Then, if I input a string in the QLineEdit and click the 'Add' button, the expected widget would not appear.

Comment: Adding child widgets and layouts to existing Qt classes is generally discouraged, and when doing that to special widgets like QLabel (which has its own "rules" for size management) is a **bad** idea. Why are you adding those widgets to a QLabel, since you're not using any of its features?

Comment: Because I would use these widget group in several class. Thus, I want to collect these widget in a QLabel. This self-implement is a module, and I can use it in anywhere. If the self-implement QLabel is not a good solution. How can I group these widget?

Comment: Just subclass QWidget instead of QLabel. QWidget is a general purpose widget from which nearly all other other widgets are derived.

Comment: There are several ways to do that, using a nested layout is usually the most common (you're already doing it in your `TypeManagerLabel`, just do the same for your main layout by adding the "grouped" layout to it. If you want to keep a more structured approach, subclass from QWidget instead and add a QLabel to its layout. Also consider that there are specific classes that exist just as they are used as containers: QGroupBox, QFrame are the most simple and commonly used, but then you also have more "page" based widgets like QTabWidget or QStackedWidget.

Comment: @Heike Thank for your helpful suggestion. Now, I use QWidget instead of QLabel. But, if I want to add new widget, bug still is reported. I have update the explanation.

Comment: @musicamante Thank for your helpful suggestion. Now, I use QWidget instead of QLabel. But, if I want to add new widget, bug still is reported. I have update the explanation.

Comment: @QiangZhang why are you still trying to set a layout and add widgets to a QLabel?!

Comment: Do you mean MyWin? I have test ```MyWin(QMainWindow)```, the bug is also reported.

Comment: Please, do **not** edit your question with a solution, especially since it has already been provided in an answer. It makes your question more difficult to understand to others. Remember that this is *not* a forum, questions and answers are not only for you, but to help others: if you continuously edit the question and add unnecessary text, it will make the whole post very confusing to others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QLabel is a very special type of widget. While it seems very simple, it is *not*: it has its own behavior when dealing with sizes, and that's in order to accomodate all requirements a widget that is primarily based on (possibly) variable text *size*, not only horizontally, but vertically also.

That said, one should never try to add layouts and child widgets to classes that are not intended to be used as container, most importantly it should *not* be done on widgets with peculiar behavior like QLabel.
Using such a widget to contain other widgets is not only a **very bad idea**, but also completely useless, as you're not actually using the real features a QLabel provides (showing text or images).

To add children and layouts, just use a nested layout, a plain QWidget class, or any other container widgets like QGroupBox or QFrame.

Even after the comments, you're still trying to add widgets to a QLabel. Remove that label, and just add the layout to the main one.

```
class TypeManagerLabel(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # ...

        layout.addLayout(btnLayout)

        self.__infoLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addLayout(self.__infoLayout)

        self.__opBtn.clicked.connect(self.addRemoveSlot)

    # ...
```

Comment: Finally, I insteal all QLabel with QWidget. Thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome. Remember that if an answer solved your issue, you should mark it as accepted by clicking on the check symbol on its left.